# How to create nested form component containing array of strings in Angular?

Tags: forms, angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am trying to create a nested reactive form component which stores an array of strings.

I was able to create a nested form component with a key value pair instead of array of strings.
Below plunker currently generates:

```
{ "emails": [ { "email": "abc@abc.com" }, { "email": "hello@abc.com" } ] }
```

but it would be nice to generate this:

```
{ "emails": [ "abc@abc.com", "hello@abc.com"] }
```

Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/D8nYpNb4h1nzinzJX0Dh?p=info

Any help is really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Using [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) you can get the format you want

```js
o = { "emails": [ { "email": "abc@abc.com" }, { "email": "hello@abc.com" } ] }
o.emails = o.emails.map(e => e.email)
console.log(JSON.stringify(o));
```

Comment: Thanks @christopher-moore! Instead of a work-around like that, I want to have the nested form component to have a value of array of strings.